# Mouseup vs Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within an AngularJS directive applied on a single element, suppose I had the code below.

```
$document.on('click', function(event){
    console.log('click');
});

$document.on('mouseup', function(event){
    console.log("mouseup");
});
```

Mouseup is always firing before click, despite this order. Will this always be the case? If click is just a mousedown followed by a mouseup, why is it firing afterwards despite the order it was registered?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: The order does not depend up the handler registration instead will depend on the order of triggerign the event... in this case the `mouseup` is triggered before the `click`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it will always be the case. The `click` event is defined to occur immediately after the `mouseup` event, the registration order will not affect that.

Comment: Any difference between browsers that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Andrew not that I know of. Some relevant testing is [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html) and you can test the order yourself [here](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/FocusEventOrdering.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the order the event handlers are executed by the browser/js engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well. If a click is a mousedown followed by a mouseup, then events are going to be trigerred in that order (mousedown, mouseup, click(as it is composed of the 2 before it,  it needs those 2 to be triggered before)) and that is something you can't change, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Order will be mouse event first and then click event.

Because your mouse will move first always , so that event will be first one in order...After your click event will fire